# If (1 = 1) Then is throwing invalid cast error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 2019, and tried this in two different computers.

Can someone explain what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, actually it was an error in the next line, which is weird because it showed the error on the previous line. Like:

```
If 1=1 Then
    If enumVariable = stringVariable
```

But it broke on the first line

Comment: Perhaps your debugger was using a stale pdb file, which can cause this behavior. I guess before you were able to debug you were prompted that the source code was different from the debugged assembly and allowed this difference.